# Content over z-index class

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to get my content over the z-index content, I have tried give it a bigger number but not working, could someone please help me with my coding to see if I have done anything wrong?
many thanks

each number will pop up a list of content when mouse hover over, however the numbers are always in front of the hovering content, for example when mouse hover over "8", the popping up content is behind number "9", I am trying to get the hovering content come to the front, any ideas?

```css
span.dropt {
  position: absolute;
  background: #006534;
  border: 2px solid #006534;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
span.dropt:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: black;
}
span.dropt:hover span {
  left: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  \ margin: 20px 0 0 70px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
}
span.dropt span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999px;
  margin: -15px 0 0 20px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 105px;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006534;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 17px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
 <span class="dropt" style="top:280px; left:490px;">8
    <span>content</span></span>

<span class="dropt" style="top:290px; left:520px;">9
    <span>content</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `z-index: 1;` from your `.dropt` class.

---

What is happening is that your `.dropt` elements have a base stacking context of 1 when you set `z-index: 1;`.

So your inner `span` has a `z-index` of 2 within 1 context. Picture this like you have different layers.

Since your second `.dropt` element is below in the markup, it's going to be on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to play with your code, looks like it might be caused of you are using `background` instead of `background-color` in your styles.  Also you had a `\` after `background: #ffffff;` might also helped to make it worse.  Normally, the `background` field are expecting several components, see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp.

After i changed `background` to `background-color`, things look alright.  Note you may need to change `left: 2%;` to some other values too

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have changed the background, thanks